# The stock item with the "7003" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

Getting error while loading product stock data with Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository class using get method with product id.
Code :-

```
$productStock = $this->_stockItemRepository->get($product->getId());
$stockqty = $productStock->getQty();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$productStock = $this->_stockItemRepository->get($product->getId());
$stockqty = $productStock->getQty();
```

StockItemRepository get function load product stock data with item id not with product id.Some times it may work because item_id and product_id are same in 'cataloginventory_stock_item' table but if product_id and item_id not same then this will throw error.

To load product stock data with product id then use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface this class.

Code:-

```
$productStock = $this->stockRegistryInterface->getStockItem($product->getId());
$stockqty = $productStock->getQty();
```